# Overlap external graphics

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I would like to overlap picture B in front of picture A.

But I dont see picture A, only if I would delete picture B.

I experience with z-index=1 and z-index=2 too. But this only work with image and text?

```html
<fo:table-row>
 <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black" padding="2pt">
  <fo:block-container>
   <fo:block-container position="absolute">
    <fo:block>
     <fo:external-graphic content-width="scale-to-fit" content-height="100%" width="100%" scaling="uniform">
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
       <xsl:value-of select="./giftCardLogo" />
      </xsl:attribute>
     </fo:external-graphic>
    </fo:block>
   </fo:block-container>
   <fo:block-container position="absolute">
    <fo:block>
     <fo:external-graphic content-width="scale-to-fit" content-height="100%" width="100%" scaling="uniform">
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
       <xsl:value-of select="./giftCardThemePicture" />
      </xsl:attribute>
     </fo:external-graphic>
    </fo:block>
   </fo:block-container>
  </fo:block-container>
 </fo:table-cell>
 <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black" padding="2pt">
  <fo:block>
   <fo:instream-foreign-object>
    <bc:barcode xmlns:bc="http://barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns">
     <xsl:attribute name="message">
      <xsl:value-of select="./giftCardNumber" />
     </xsl:attribute>
     <bc:datamatrix>
      <bc:module-width>1.0mm</bc:module-width>
     </bc:datamatrix>
    </bc:barcode>
   </fo:instream-foreign-object>
  </fo:block>
 </fo:table-cell>
 <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black" padding="2pt">
  <fo:block>&#x00A0;</fo:block>
 </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

(You don't mention the format of the images you are using, the output format, and which version of FOP, so it's not easy to give an you an answer)

If I understand correctly, you have two images and want to place them in the same position, one as background and one as foreground; for example, one could have horizontal lines, the other vertical lines, you expect to see a grid in the output, but you only see the "last" set of lines.

I performed a test with FOP 1.1, using both png and svg images with transparent background and different levels of object transparency (alpha channel), and creating PDF output (probably the most common choices): everyting appears as expected.

So, your problem could be caused by:

- **the format of your images**: png, gif and svg support transparent background / alpha channel; jpg doesn't
- **the SVG features your images use**: even if you use svg images, some features (effects, patterns, referenced images, ...) are handled creating a rasterized image, [thus losing transparency](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/graphics.html#svg-problems)
- **the output format**: [FOP's page about graphics formats](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/graphics.html) states that for gif and png images "Transparency is supported but not guaranteed to work with every output format"; PDF is ok

Lastly, `z-index` [is not supported at the moment](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-property-z-index): images are "stacked" in the output according to the document order, so the first one is under the following ones, the last one is in the foreground.